# Azure DevOps generating error when using GitVersion to generate version number

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines, gitversion

I'm working on an Azure DevOps release pipeline, and wanting to use GitVersion to auto-generate the semantic version number for my builds; I've implemented this without problem in the CI build, but when I come to do the same for the release pipeline, I get the following error:

```
2021-03-31T06:33:24.9941116Z Executing GenerateSetVersionMessage for 'AzurePipelines'.
2021-03-31T06:33:24.9961020Z ##[error]Unable to process command '##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]0.1.0' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2021-03-31T06:33:24.9979344Z ##[error]Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'buildId')
2021-03-31T06:33:25.0085671Z Executing GenerateBuildLogOutput for 'AzurePipelines'.
```

The YAML for the steps to install and run GitVersion is:

```
steps:
- task: gittools.gittools.setup-gitversion-task.gitversion/setup@0
  displayName: 'Set up assembly versioning'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.3.6

- task: gittools.gittools.execute-gitversion-task.gitversion/execute@0
  displayName: 'Calculate version number'
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_MyRepo'
    useConfigFile: true
    configFilePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_MyRepo/GitVersion.yml'
```

Is the GitVersion task supported for release pipelines, or just for build pipelines?

Answer (score 1):

The [**GitVersion**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion&targetId=908caa0a-f48e-4597-a3f3-6cc82d04dbb1) is a build task, it might be not well available to release pipelines. According to the logs you shared, the **GitVersion** task would execute the "[**UpdateBuildNumber**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#updatebuildnumber-override-the-automatically-generated-build-number)" command.

The "**UpdateBuildNumber**" command is used to override the automatically generated build number with a new build number you specify for current build. It is only available to CI build pipelines (Both Classic and YAML). You can't use this command in a build run to update the build number of another build. And It is also not available to release pipelines.

```
##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]new-build-number
```

If you want to override the automatically generated release name with a new name you specify for current release, you can use the "[**UpdateReleaseName**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#updatereleasename-rename-current-release)" command in your release pipelines. The usage of this command is similar to "**UpdateBuildNumber**".

```
##vso[release.updatereleasename]new-release-name
```

To view more details, you can see "[**Logging commands**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash)".

**[UPDATE]**

If you just want to update the release name, why don't you directly using the "**UpdateReleaseName**" command in your release pipeline?

You should use the **GitVersion** task in the build pipeline that generated the artifact that was used as source for the release pipeline.

After executing the **GitVersion** task in the build pipeline to generate and update a new build number, in the release pipeline that uses the build artifact as source, you can use the [predefined Build variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) '**`$(Build.BuildNumber)`**' to get the build number, and use the "**UpdateReleaseName**" command to update the release name with the build number.

For example, you can add a [Bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) to execute the following command in the release pipeline.

```
echo "##vso[release.updatereleasename]$(Build.BuildNumber)"
```

This will update the release name to be same as the build number of the associated build.

Comment: That sounds feasible - as I said in the original question, the GitVersion build task worked fine in the build pipeline, so I knew the GitVersion configuration was valid. Can I prevent GitVersion from automatically trying to update the build number, and letting me update the release name instead, via the logging command?

Comment: Hi @DavidKeaveny, I have updated my answer with more details. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go and let you know how it went

Comment: One step forward, two steps back.. I can set the version number on my build pipeline and pass it through to the release pipeline if I use publish artefacts from the build pipeline, but then I can't build my Docker images because I don't have a source artefact. If I use the source artefact I can build the Docker image, but there's no build number to set as my release number :(